# Bootstrap 4 Vertical Timeline Columns aren't on same row [Large Margin]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, timeline, margins

I am coding my first website. I am attempting to create a vertical timeline using Bootstrap 4, where the bar of the timeline is in between two columns. Currently, I cannot place text in the first column and an image directly to the right in the second column. The image is always pushed down to the next row. When I examine the element, I notice a large margin (orange area). How do I remove this? 
This is my first post on Stack Overflow. I apologize if this is a bit long.
Thanks!

[Relevant Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGkYp.png)

```
<div class="row mt-3 no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="timeline">
        <div class="timeline-item-left">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-right p-3 mr-0">
            <h3>December 2017</h3>
            <h5>Big Basin Redwoods State Park </h5>
            Berry Creek Falls Loop | 10 Miles             
          </div>
          <div class="offset-md-6 col-md-6 text-left">
            <a href="adventure_images/big_basin.jpg">
              <img src="adventure_images/big_basin.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Big Basin" width="150"> 
            </a>
          </div>         
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.timeline {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Containers around content */
.timeline-item-left {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
/*    background-image: <img src="adventure_images/spiration_light.png">;
    background-repeat: repeat-x; */
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.timeline-item-right {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
/*    background-image: <img src"adventure_images/spiration_light.png">;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;*/
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Inspection of Element Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg2li.png)

[Website Link (for more detailed inspection)](https://robertspragg.github.io/portfolio/adventures)

Comment: Hi Robert, You should read the SO guidelines. It is not a good idea to screenshot code and attach an image. Please add the relevant code to your question and format it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css in your style.

```
 .timeline-item-left,.timeline-item-left {display: flex}
```

and remove class offset-md-6.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
.timeline-item-left {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

remove **offset-md-6**

```
<div class="offset-md-6 col-md-6 text-left">
```